# Redefining the context of an event handler

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a listener for the event `show_keyboard`. In the handler, I need to unbind from this event. In this case, the event is thrown from a native android plugin.

```
appView.sendJavascript("cordova.fireWindowEvent('native.showkeyboard', { 'keyboardHeight':" + Integer.toString(keyboardHeight)+"});");
```

In `addHeightHandler`, I need `this` to be the parent to `addHeightHandler` in order to unbind from it. Therefore I'm passing `self` when calling `addHeightHandler`. However, when I do this, I cannot get access to `e` and the `keyboardHeight` attribute.

Note: my employer insists it must be done like this, without anonymous functions or global setting of the `self` variable

```
/*
 * When keyboard is shown, add height of keyboard to body to make scrollable. 
 */
this.addHeightHandler = function (e) {
    keyboardHeight = e.keyboardHeight;
    //e is undefined 
    //do some stuff to add keyboard height
    window.removeEventListener('show_keyboard', this.addHeightHandler);
};

/*
 * Listen for showkeyboard events thrown by native code on Android
 */
this.addKeyboardListeners = function () {
    var self = this;
    window.addEventListener('native.showkeyboard', function () {
        self.addHeightHandler(self)
    }, false);
};
```

I know there are other ways of doing this, but this is the way I've been directed to do it. I believe passing `self` to `addHeightHandler`  means `e` will be overwritten, is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the following:

```
this.addKeyboardListeners = function () {
    var self = this;
    window.addEventListener(eventConstants.nativeShowKeyboard, function () {
        self.addHeightHandler(self);
    });
};
```

Is passing `self` as the value of `e`.

What you can do is bind the `addHeightHandler` function to the desired context. In `addKeyboardListeners`, you could:

```
this.addKeyboardListeners = function () {
    var handler = this.addHeightHandler.bind(this);
    addEventListener(eventConstants.nativeShowKeyboard, handler);
};
```

What the above does is "bind" the context of the `addHeightHandler` function to `this`, meaning that when it is called, the `this` keyword inside the function will be a reference to whatever `this` was when you bound it.

The function will still take `e` as an argument, so when the event occurs and the handler is run, `e` will still be the event.

Comment: What do yo mean? As well, looking at the OP, are you unbinding the same event? You have `"show_keyboard"` and `eventConstants.nativeShowKeyboard`, are those the same?

Comment: yes it is, i edited question. actually, in the end i didnt need to unbind, so your answer works perfectly. thanks!